# `Interaction.plot` function in R is missing a factor level

Tags: r, plot

I am using `interaction.plot` function to plot an interaction between factor variables `A` and `B`.

```
interaction.plot(A, B, y)  # `y` is a continuous variable
```

I've entered variables correctly, but when the plot comes up there is only one line instead of two (`B` has 2 levels so I expect 2 lines).

Interestingly, when I tried `interaction.plot(B, A, y)`, a level is also missing from `A`.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Thank you. I will be trying this when I return to my analysis and will certainly give feedback on whether it is solved. There are missing observations so I suspect your solution will be the correct one.

Comment: That was very unhelpful. I have several projects on at one time and cannot return to my analysis at will - only at specific times. I said I would give feedback and would have done shortly.